# What is specification connectors used in dji manifold 2

Tags: connector, uart, io

i'm Filipe
I'm looking about what is connectors specification  used in DJI manifold 2, unfortunately in datasheet there is'not information about this specification only it talks about communication port.

Somebody could you help me?

I need to know whatconnectors specification to buy for my search.

1 - RJ 45
2 - USB A
3 - HDMI
4 - Antenna ports
5 - connector XT 30
6 - Power indicator
7 - USB micro B
8 - UART PORT, what is connector specification ?
9 - CAN PORT, what is connector specification ?
10 - I/O PORT, what is connector specification ?

[image]

Comment: I recommend you join [drones.stackexchange.com](https://drones.stackexchange.com/) to support that community and ask this question there.

Comment: This site is not for product usage questions, but only for design questions or questions which supply design-equivalent details.   Thus questions here are required to be supported by key information; the information you are asking for is precisely the information you are required to supply when asking a question on this site, which means that we cannot help you.